# How to unhide multiple objects in the outliner?

Tags: outliner

In outliner i select multiple hidden objects then i want just to turn on that eyeball icon, to unhide. But i can only do it per object. Tried to press 'alt' to have 'multiple' effect but not working. They are not stored in a single collection , but rather distributed on many collections.

Is it possible ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes it is possible
Just select all of them and hit alt+H on the keyboard in 3d view port

Comment: Alt H will unhide all hidden object. Not the selected objects in outliner.

Comment: If you mark this as the correct answer you should maybe edit your question to "unhide all hidden objects" (and then it's maybe a duplicate question?), since the answer doesn't help if you only want to unhide specific objects which you selected beforehand.

Comment: Okay,sorry about that,other than this way,I don't know any other way to do so but it works for me in similar cases cause it's easier if you have many objects that you want to unhide,just unhide all and hide unrequired

Comment: If that's the case than of course it makes it easier to unhide all and hide the few that should be kept hidden. The term 'multiple' suggests it's meant as 'many, but not all' - which would be interesting for people who have for example 100 hidden objects and want to unhide only 50 of them. Maybe upvote the answer, but not mark it as 'answered' so that someone keeps looking for it? I would be interested in a 'real' answer, too 